# Localization by Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: silverlight, binding, resources, localization, dictionary

I have a silverlight project that handle multilanguage by Resources files. Now I should remove resource file and read messages from database.
When I use resource file I bind controls like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings.User, Source={StaticResource Localizer}}"/>
```

Now I use dictionary like this:

```
public class Localizer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
...
    public Dictionary<string, string> Strings
    {
         get { return _strings; }
         set
         {
             _strings = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("Strings");
         }
    }
...
}
```

and bind controls to this dictionary like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Strings[User], Source={StaticResource Localizer}}"/>
```

It work correctly, but I should change all binding in application and use ([]) bracket instead of (.) dot.
Is there any way to prevent of this changes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use derive from [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class like in the following snippet if you have Silverlight 4

```
class Localizer
{
    public Strings Strings { get; set; }
}

public class Strings : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, string> values;

    public Strings(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string value;
        bool success = values.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out value);
        result = value;
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: tanx dear Hasan Khan, but are you sure that we can bind UIEelement to dynamic object.
I do like your sample but in VS output I get System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'User' property not found on '....Strings' '....Strings' (HashCode=10857028). BindingExpression: Path='Strings.User' DataItem='....Localizer' (HashCode=30604389); target element is ...
but when I get a property from Strings in code, not in xaml it work correctly. Do you know what do I do?

Comment: Just got to know this is bug in silverlight http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522119/databinding-to-dynamic-objects-is-broken#

Comment: Thanks for you attention.
Do you have another solution for my first problem?